# Checkbox Order Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, checkbox

I created a function that will put all the checked items into a text area.. but my problem is the displaying of checked items is indexed.

for example:

[x] checkbox1 (second tick) 
 
[x] checkbox2(first tick)
[x] checkbox3 (third tick)

now the display goes like this

checkbox1 - > checkbox2 - > checkbox3

it should be checkbox2 - > checkbox1 - > checkbox3

here is the function:

```
function checkTick()
{

    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
            var selectedvalue=[];
            $(":checkbox:checked").each(function(){

                selectedvalue.push($(this).attr("value"));

            });
            document.getElementById('txtSignOff').value = selectedvalue.join("->");

        });

}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Global Scope**: Set the variable `selectedvalue` in the global scope. Rather than pushing each checkbox value, just push only the current checkbox value.

**Pop Value on Unchecking**: When a checkbox is unchecked/unticked, then the corresponding value should be popped from the array, provided all values in the array should be distinct.

```
var selectedvalue=[];    

    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
                //If checked then push the value
                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    selectedvalue.push($(this).attr("value"));
                }else{
                   //This is what pops the value from the array when the checkbox is unchecked.
                    selectedvalue.splice(selectedvalue.indexOf($(this).attr("value")),1); 
                }
                document.getElementById('txtSignOff').value = selectedvalue.join("->");    
    });
```

**Function blockizing**: You don't need to blockize it into the function `checkTick`. jQuery utilities provides you such a thing when an event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing correct but your variable get's overridden, so it's taking values incorrectly. Make it global

```
var selectedvalue=[];
```

Another important point is "here no need to make .each for every checkbox"

and now the function

```
function checkTick()
{
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
            selectedvalue.push($(this).attr("value"));
            document.getElementById('txtSignOff').value = selectedvalue.join("->");

        });
}
```

Comment: It should only be pushed when checked, and needs to be removed from the array on uncheck.